# How to fetch total game viewers for the new Twitch API using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, twitch

Due to the new twitch API, there is no specified api response that returns the number of viewers per game. The only viewer_count option the documentation gives is the amount of viewers per stream.

Top Games: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-top-games

Get Streams: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-streams

I am guessing that I need to group all active streams by game, then find the sum of viewers from each group.

Any ideas on how this would look in code? I am using reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to get all channels streaming that game and sum up the viewers of each channel. However this data will change all the time, so for most purposes it should be fine to just get the top 50 or so channels, to get an estimate of the total viewership.
I am not well versed in JavaScript but the pseudo code would look something like this:

```
streams = get("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?game_id=12345&first=50")["data"]
viewership = sum(streams, key = stream -> stream["viewer_count"])
```